# Copy hidden text in div or button element to clipboard with click function

Tags: javascript, onclick, onclicklistener

I have spent a couple of days looking at examples of this. I believe I am either missing something or simply misusing it. I created my own version with slight modifications but it isn't working for me. I believe it is Javascript not jQuery but I do have other functions in the site with jQuery so I kept this in the header.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Below this, I have the following script. I have seen a lot of examples using input containers but I need a simple click function to copy text that is not visible but in the element as a value. I want to be able to let the user click a "SPAN12" button and the elements needed to create a span12 for layout should copy to the clipboard. Then the user can paste the div element with a span12 class into the textarea. I guess another option is to let the code add it directly to the textarea with a click of the button labeled span12 but if not, then at least copying to clipboard is a great start. I just don't want to have the text show and I don't want it to be in the input to copy from, just a button. I have seen lots of examples with the 2 just mentioned but none in the way I am picturing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#toCopy").on('click', function(){
        document.getElementById("toCopy").addEventListener("copy", myFunction);
    });
});
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("copied").innerHTML = "You copied text!"
}
    </script>
```

The element I am trying to manipulate is as follows.

```
<button type="text" id="toCopy" onclick="myFunction()" value="&lt;div class='span12'&gt;&lt;/div&gt;">Span 12</button>
<p id="copied"></p>
```

Comment: You need to have a click handler for your `#toCopy` button.

Comment: @MingleLi I changed it to this following code. I have the myFunction() working so when I click on the button, the text displays however, the content that I am trying to copy in the value is not copying. $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#toCopy").on('click', function(){
  document.getElementById("toCopy").addEventListener("copy", myFunction);
 });
});
function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("copied").innerHTML = "You copied text!"
}